# Add a column based on the dynamically named columns

Tags: r, dplyr

A new column must be added to the existed dataframe so, that it is the mean of some other columns which are selected dynamiclly.

I prefer using dplyr, and thus the solution might look like something as follows:

```
selected_columns <- c("am", "mpg")
dplyr::mutate_at(mt_cars, vars(selected_columns), funs(new_col = rowMeans(.)))
```

Is there a way to modify this chunk or is another approach required?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here, we just need to subset the columns of data (`.` ) with the string `vector` and get the `rowMeans`

```
library(dplyr)
mtcars  %>%
     mutate(new_col = rowMeans(.[selected_columns]))
```

---

`mutate` doesn't have the `funs` parameter (`funs` is already deprecated with `list`) and it is in `mutate_if/mutate_at/mutate_all`.

Comment: Thanks for your remark concerning mutate_at - it's been fixed.  And great thanks for the solution itself!

Comment: @ArtemZefirov  `mutate_at/mutate_if` etc are looping through columns separately.  So, it is basically a container where there is no communication between columns.  So, applying `rowMeans` is not going to change anything while `rowMeans` require some dim attributes, but the columns are vectors